# Using a float in Javascript in a hash function

Tags: javascript, floating-point, type-conversion, integer, hash-function

I Have a hash function like this.

```
class Hash {
  static rotate (x, b) {
    return (x << b) ^ (x >> (32-b));
  }
  static pcg (a) {
    let b = a;
    for (let i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
      a = Hash.rotate((a^0xcafebabe) + (b^0xfaceb00c), 23);
      b = Hash.rotate((a^0xdeadbeef) + (b^0x8badf00d), 5);
    }
    return a^b;
  }
}
// source Adam Smith: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/proceduralcontent/AuvxuA1xqmE/T8t88r2rfUcJ
```

I use it like this.

```
console.log(Hash.pcg(116)); // Output: -191955715
```

As long as I send an integer in, I get an integer out. Now here comes the problem. If I have a floating number as input, rounding will happen. The number Hash.pcg(1.1) and Hash.pcg(1.2) will yield the same. I want different inputs to yield different results. A possible solution could be to multiply the input so the decimal is not rounded down, but is there a more elegant and flexible solution to this?

Is there a way to convert a floating point number to a unique integer? Each floating point number would result in a different integer number.

Performance is important.

Comment: When the [BigInt](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/BigInt) type becomes widely available you'll be able to use that for all your bitwise operations.

Answer (score 1):

This isn't quite an answer, but I was running out of room to make it a comment. :)

You'll hit a problem with integers outside of the 32-bit range as well as with non-integer values.

JavaScript handles all numbers as 64-bit floating point. This gives you exact integers over the range -9007199254740991 to 9007199254740991 (±(2^53 - 1)), but the bit-wise operators used in your hash algorithm (`^`, `<<`, `>>`) only work in a 32-bit range.

Since there are far more non-integer numbers possible than integers, no one-to-one mapping is possible with ordinary numbers. You could work something out with `BigInt`s, but that will likely lead to comparatively much slower performance.

If you're willing to deal with the performance hit, your can use JavaScript buffer functions to get at the actual bits of a floating point number. <del>(I'd say more now about how to do that, but I've got to run!)</del>

*Edit... back from dinner...*

You can convert JavaScript's standard `number` type, which is 64-bit floating point, to a `BigInt` like this:

```
let dv = new DataView(new ArrayBuffer(8));
dv.setFloat64(0, Math.PI);
console.log(dv.getFloat64(0), dv.getBigInt64(0), dv.getBigInt64(0).toString(16).toUpperCase())
```

The output from this is:

> 3.141592653589793 4614256656552045848n "400921FB54442D18"

The first item shows that the number was properly stored as byte array, the second shows the `BigInt` created from the same bits, and the last is the same `BigInt` over again, but in hex to better show the floating point data format.

Once you've converted a `number` like this to a `BigInt` (which is not the same numeric value, but it is the same string of bits) every possible value of number will be uniquely represented.

The same bit-wise operators you used in your algorithm above will work with `BigInt`s, but without the 32-bit limitation. I'm guessing that for best results you'd want to change the `32` in your code to `64`, and use 16-digit (instead of 8-digit) hex constants as hash keys.